# Eclipse Helios & Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle

Tags: eclipse, marketplace, eclipse-3.6, dark-theme

Please help me solve this problem.
I started studying to be a programmer. I was given the program Eclipse Helios (Wascana).
I understand that the school uses it because it is fast, unlike the latest versions.
I can't change the theme. Marketplace gives an error

`MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?product=org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product&os=win32&runtime.version=3.6.0.v20100505&client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc .core&java.version=1.6.0_20&product.version=1.3.0.20100617-0520&ws=win32. connection reset`

I understand that the incompatibility of versions of marketplaces.
Wanted to manually download the Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle theme (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle)
but he won't let me do it?
How can I put Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle on my current eclips?

P.S Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415

Comment: They're not doing anyone any favors by having you use a 13 year old release. Clicking the orange heart icon on the Marketplace page, under the Install button, will expose what the underlying Update Site is for you to use with the Install New Software dialog off of the Help menu, but there is no guarantee that they even still support a release this old. Which again, is from over a decade ago.

Comment: A lot of current code is not going to work on such an ancient release. There were substantial changes between Eclipse 3 and the current Eclipse 4.

Comment: This dark theme patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this. Contrary to what you say, newer versions of Eclipse are faster and support the latest Java versions. The school should of course use the latest version of Eclipse and the latest long-term version of Java.

Comment: Can you download a zip distribution of eclipse, unpack it and use it for your work and then suffer the schools eclipse until it works.